# org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: why programmatically created IResource is not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin that setups a generic bare eclipse project creating a folder structure and moving files into it.

I create my IProject folders tree (an IPath such as "/it/plugin/sample/template") with something like this

```
private void createFolderStructure(IProject workspaceProject, IPath brokerSchemaPath) throws CoreException {
    if (workspaceProject == null) { throw new IllegalStateException("The workspace project where the broker schema has to be created cannot be null."); }

    IFolder bsFolder = workspaceProject.getFolder(brokerSchemaPath);

    if (!bsFolder.getParent().exists()) {
        createFolderStructure(workspaceProject, bsFolder.getParent().getProjectRelativePath());
    }

    if (!bsFolder.exists()) { bsFolder.create(false, true, progressMonitor); }
}
```

This is working fine: the filesystem and the projects seems to reflect the IPath created ([project root]/it/plugin/sample/template), but when I try to move an IResource into the new leaf-folder ("../template) it raises something like that:

> Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException:
>   Resource '/it' does not exist.    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:341)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkMoveRequirements(Resource.java:408)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.assertMoveRequirements(Resource.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.move(Resource.java:1618)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.move(Resource.java:1598)

To move the resource i'm using this simple stub

```
private void moveResource(IProject workspaceProject, String resourceName,
        String from, String to) throws CoreException {

    IFile resource = workspaceProject.getFile(from+"/"+resourceName);
    if (!resource.exists()) { return; }

    resource.move(new Path(to+"/"+resourceName), false, progressMonitor);
}
```

What's wrong with that? Or what i'm missing?

I also try to use the moveResource method to rename in-place a resource and it works fine.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well what is the destination path for the move? If the path starts with '/' it must be a full path in the workspace starting with the project name.

Comment: @greg-449 good point! The destination path was not started with the project name. I change the target path with  `new Path("/"+workspaceProject.getName()+to+"/"+resourceName)` and it works like a charm. I was missing that the IPath was relative to the workspace root. I thougth the resource.move implicitally refers to the project where that resource belongs. Many thanks!